# RegEx - Finding multiple dashes in entire string... and a little more

Tags: regex

So I am HORRIBLE with RegEx... can you help me with the following?

- only allows 52 total characters
- only has "a-z", "A-Z", "0-9", & "-" (letters, numbers, and dashes)
- does not start with "-" (dash)
- does not end with "-" (dash)
- does not have "--" (two consecutive dashes together)
- does not have more than 2 "-" (dashes) in the entire string (this is what I'm having problems with)

So here is a helpful list (I guess):

```
Pass:
    abc-123
    abc-123-abc
Fail: 
    -abc-123             (fails due to starting with a dash)
    abc-123-             (fails due to ending with a dash)
    abc-123-abc-123      (fails due to 3 dashes)
    abc-12#-abc          (failed due to having a character that is not a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or a dash)
```

This is what I currently have, but feel free to change it however you would like:

```
(?!.*--)^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,50}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but as mentioned above, I'm horrible with expressions. My expression works, it just doesn't find more than two dashes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This regex (`^[a-z0-9]+(-?[a-z0-9]+){0,2}$`) does roughly what you want: https://regex101.com/r/0tJEaI/2 The only part that's nearly impossible to take care of is the 52 character limit.

Comment: You can add another negative lookahead to your regex:`(?!(.*-){3,})` https://regex101.com/r/2byFNI/2

Comment: @Nick thank you! I kept trying (?!.*-{3,})... again, thank you!

Comment: @Marc the joys of parentheses! :-)

Comment: Should it allow MAX 50 character or EXACT 50 characters?

Comment: Should it have at least one character or empty string is a match too?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)-flavoured regex:

```
/^(?!.*\-\-)(?!.*\-.+\-.*\-)(?!-)[a-z0-9-]{0,52}(?<!-)$/gmi
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PxPBCO/6/)

The regex can be made self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing mode*:

```
/
^                    # match beginning of line
(?!.*\-\-.*$)        # the line may not contain two consecutive hyphens
(?!.*\-.*\-.*\-.*$)  # the line may not contain more than two hyphens
(?!-)                # the first char cannot be a hyphen               
[a-z0-9-]{0,52}      # match 0-52 letters, digits and hyphens
(?<!-)               # the last char cannot be a hyphen
$                    # match end of the line
/xgmi                # free-spacing, global, multiline, case indifferent modes
```

`(?!.*\-\-.*$)`, `(?!.*\-.*\-.*\-.*$)` and `(?!-)` are *negative lookaheads*; `(?<!-)` is a *negative lookbehind*.

This matches each line of a string (convenient for showing test cases at the *demo*). If the string contains a single line the regex can be simplified somewhat:

```
\A(?!.*\-\-)(?!.*\-.+\-.*\-)(?!-)[a-z0-9-]{0,52}(?<!-)\z
```

Not that `\A` and `\z` are beginning and end of string anchors, whereas `^` and `$` are beginning and end of line anchors. Compare the negative lookaheads in this regex with those in the earlier one.

Should it matter, this matches empty strings.

Comment: The "negative lookbehind" feature may not be supported in all browsers. Not really sure if that's a major issue?

Comment: Most regex engines support fixed-length lookbehinds (see *Language Features, Part 1* [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines)) but if you are using one that doesn't you could remove `(?<!-)` and change `(?!-)` to `(?!-|.*-$)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use assert a maximum of 52 chars in a positive lookahead.

Then match 1 or more times `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` and repeat 0, 1 or 2 times or more times the same pattern preceded with a `-`

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,52}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,2}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of line
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,52}$` Match any of the listed 1-52 times and assert end of string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed to prevent matching an empty string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match `-` and 1+ times any of the listed without the `-`
- `){0,2}` Close group and repeat 0-2 times
- `$` End of line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v2ObTX/1)